# AngularJS page freezes after changing view

Tags: angularjs, view

I'm having problem in AngularJS when I changed view it turns the page into silhoutte gray/black and the whole page is freezed or disabled. There is nothing you can click. You need to manually refresh it to turn to normal again. There are also no error logs in the console. How to fix it?

```
angular.module('myApp.loginController', [])

.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.loginSubmit = function(){
        $state.go('customer_home');
    }

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.loginData = {};
    }

});
```

main.html

```
...some codes here...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loginSubmit()">Login</button>
...some codes here...
```

here is the look of page when freezed after change view

[image]
here is the look of page after manual refresh

[image]

Comment: I didn't include it because it was just the simple direct call of the view but I'll update the post.

Comment: where does the default state go?

Comment: to the customer home page with the state customer_home mentioned on my code and the sample view of that page are the pictures above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use the $uibModal service. The traditional way of BS modal is not a convenient way in AngularJS. Then in the controller of the $uibModal is to inject $uibModalInstance then use the close function. To understand more, here is the docu of the service: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Sorry to not to mention that the main.html code is a part of BS modal because at first I thought it doesn't cause anything of the bug.

main.html

```
...some codes here...
<script type="text/ng-template" id="loginModal" ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div id="loginModalCont" class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">LOG IN</h4>
        </div>
        <form ng-model="loginData">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="loginData.username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loginSubmit()">Login</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">Signup</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

mainController.js

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, $uibModal) {

    ...some codes here...

    $scope.openModal = function(){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'loginModal',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        });
    }

});
```

loginController.js

```
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $state, $uibModalInstance) {

    $scope.loginSubmit = function(){
        $state.go('member_home');
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.loginData = {};
    }

    $scope.close = function(){
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

});
```